# Java project not compatible with legacy versions of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compatibility

I developed a java program in Eclipse Luna using JavaSE1.8. I wanted to generate some static program slices and the only slicing tool I could find was Indus. Indus requires j2sdk1.4.2 and jre 1.5.0 and must be executed on Eclipse 3.2. Unfortunately my project is not compatible with this set up and so I get all sorts of compilation errors when I import my project across.

So - my project works on Eclipse Luna, but not in Eclipse 3.2 and Indus only works on Eclipse 3.2 but not Eclipse Luna. Does anyone know what I can do resolve this?

Comment: what sorts of compilation errors are you getting?

Comment: I get errors like "The type ArrayList is not generic, it can't be parameterised with arguments Integer". I was reading around and I found that some people fixed this error by using a more up to date version of Java. But this isn't an option for me :(

Comment: Generics requires you compile your project against at least 1.5. Are you?

Comment: My compiler compliance level is 1.4. I changed it to 5.0 and I get this "parameterized types are only available if source level is 5.0
 The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer>"